# How to find a user's action on an email using gmail API

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to see how a user interacts with emails, and was wondering if there is any function I can use to see whether the person read an email or not.

I used  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get and I am able to get most of the information on each email message, such as From, To, CC, Date. However, it doesn't seem to say anything about whether the user performed any action on it, such as reading it, starring it etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [history.list()](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list) and the [sync guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync), it will tell you label modifications on a message over time.  So you can, for example, see when UNREAD or INBOX labels were removed.